# Safaricom dashboard does not show all the test credentials

Tags: mpesa

I am working on Safaricom Daraja API B2C but some of the required test credentials are not displayed in the Safaricom Dashboard.

[image]

As you can see above, the initiator name and security credentials are not provided yet they are needed in the B2C API call.

How do I get these credentials.

**EDIT:**
This question was asked before Safaricom upgraded to the new Daraja Dashboard. The problem has now been sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, for some unknown reason to us, Safaricom chose to hide the test credentials and if you need them, you have to write them an email at **apisupport@safaricom.co.ke** and request for the test credentials. You will get a response in less than an hour with shortcodes and initiators that you can use for test.

Source -> https://survtechnologies.co.ke/get-test-credentials-safaricom-m-pesa-daraja-api/

Answer (score 0):

The test Credentials are on the simulator link, bottom right redirects to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with the new mpesa portal2.0 - It is straight-forward

Answer (score 0):

With the updated Daraja V2, you can get the test credentials in the simulator.

1. Login to https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/APIs/
2. Select **C2B** or any other
3. On the simulator select your app
4. By now an icon with square and two bars will have appear on the down, right corner
5. Click on the icon and copy the credentials.